# Why'd my answer get turned into a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

At [Bug with quantity of float numbers on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289555/bug-with-quantity-of-float-numbers-on-c#comment23318599_16289555), my answer got turned into a comment.  I'm trying to figure out why.

I find this a little confusing, since it's a complete and correct answer to the poster's question.  Having a look at the FAQ:

```
commentary on the question or other answers
```

Yes, I suppose it's commentary on the question, in that the question asks why a piece of code behaves as it does and it points out the problem in the code.  Seems like most answers fit that bill, though.

```
asking another, different question
```

There's certainly a question mask.  It seems like a stretch to argue that the question isn't rhetorical.

```
“thanks!” or “me too!” responses
```

Nope.

```
exact duplicates of other answers
```

No other answers.

```
barely more than a link to an external site
```

Nope.

```
not even a partial answer to the actual question
```

Well, it's not a partial answer.  It's a complete answer.

Comment: How exactly does that answer the question?

Comment: @animuson: If you read the question, you see that the asker wonders why his code suddenly fails when he adds a new local variable.  It's because everything is conditioned on an uninitialised variable.

Comment: Well your answer certainly doesn't explain why your question is related to anything. If it's really the answer, maybe you should expand on it (as in, you shouldn't be asking a question in your answer anyways).

Comment: @animuson: Rhetorical questions are verboten in answers?  I do see how the answer could be improved now that you've pointed out a concrete deficiency.

Comment: Asking questions in an answer makes it look like you're not sure, also known as *guessing*. A lot of answers that ask questions ends up deleted or converted to comments because it's hard to tell if it's an *actual answer* or just a suggestion unrelated to the question at hand. You have to remember that not everyone reviewing things like this are proficient in the language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asking a question, even if it's hypothetical, is going to look like a comment to a mod, particularly when you don't actually explain why you're asking it. Instead of:

> What's the deal with wrapping everything in if (x1 >= 0)?

Try:

> You're wrapping the entire function in `if (x1 >= 0)` before you've even initialized it, so your program will randomly choose one of the two branches. (etc. about why adding a local changes the behavior and ways to fix the problem)

Comment: Cool.  Is there a way to get the edited answer undeleted?  (I'm not going to shed many tears over this; it just strikes me as a failure of the moderation process that's better not left uncorrected.)

Comment: @tmyklebu Flag it for mod attention

Comment: @tmyklebu - It's not really a failure of the moderation process. Answers should look like... well... answers. That's what the Q&A is all about. So when you post something that looks like you're unsure of yourself, others may be unsure as well. Consider this: If a moderator thought you were asking a question, do you think it's possible that some other user with the same problem as the asker may misunderstand as well, missing the fact that you had indeed answered the question, just in a not-obvious fashion?  With that said, your post now looks like a legitimate Stack Overflow answer. Nice edits!